# How can I make my Raycast2D touch postion more precise?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a problem in my mobile game , that I'm currently developing in Unity.
In my script I detect touches via a RaycastHit2D and then destroy the touched object (In my case a raindrop).
The only problem is that when I run the game and touch the raindrop, it doesn't always work.
It only works , when I  slightly touch below it.
The Circle Collider 2D I'm using for my raindrop prefab is alright , so I don't think it causes the trouble.

My Script:

```
void Update()
{
    GetInput();    
}

private void GetInput()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Vector2 WorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(WorldPoint, Vector2.zero);
            GameObject collider = hit.collider.gameObject;
            if (collider.tag == "Tropfen")
            {
                Destroy(collider);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do a circle cast to do a circle around the touch point?

Comment: You may debug you rays using OnDrawGizmos() method, use Debug.DrawLine(...) to see, where you ray goes to